# What's the best way to map a record in one format to another?

Tags: java, data-structures, mapping

My record is represented by plain text.
For example:-

```
//Record in format A
Header|meta.1|meta.2|...
body|data.1|data.2|...

//Now I want to convert it to record in format B
Meta=[meta.1, meta.2]
Content=[data.1, data.2]
Summary=[{meta.1, data.1}, {meta.2, data.2}]
//condition is possible
type=if meta.1==TYPE1 then T1
```

The above formats are just for an instance. I'm asking for a general idea about coverting records between different formats.

I know I can first parse the record in first format and store the result somewhere and then populate the record in second format all in Java.

But I am seeking a better way that is more maintainable, scalable and robust. Is it possible to write all the mapping rules in configuration/template files and when I use it, just throw the data in and get the result. When the mapping changes, the only thing I need to do is modify the corresponding configuration/template file.

Any idea is welcome. Thanks..

Comment: Yes it is possible using mapping files. Those have the .java/.class extension and the rules look like Java expressions. :) - Seriously, you might have to do some coding since you not only change the format of a single record but group parts of records etc. and I doubt there is a library that can do that in a highly generic way with just a set of rules. - If there is such a library it would require kind of a programming language (ore more specific a DSL) and then you're not that far from Java anymore. You might however try and use an interpreted JVM language like Scala instead of Java.

Comment: That's funny. :) Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a Translator to me.

http://www.eaipatterns.com/MessageTranslator.html